# A video editing app that has the option to blur or hide parts/areas (e.g. sensitive/personal data) of a video

Tags: android, video, video-editing, screen-recording

I have to create a screen recorded video about "how to remotely wake up/startup computer then also remotely unlock the computer from logon screen using particular apps that remotely boots and controls the computer". I will use & show my own experience about remote controlling the computers as an example to the video but it involves actions like inputting user password, showing IP addresses and displaying personal information to the public. Of course, I won't allow anyone to know any intimate & private details about myself & my possessions from the video so I want to, and it's best to blur, pixelate or hide some particular areas of the video from being shown publicly to the viewers.

I've already asked & searched the internet and browsed the Google Play store for apps that can do this option if they ever exist for android but they only suggest & give me video editing apps that have no feature to cover up sensitive data. Or maybe I didn't search thoroughly and must try searching again.

Please do consider this because I've already made and uploaded a video to Youtube that is already merged with lots of cropped videos just to omit private infos from being seen by viewers. I appreciate your attention in giving your time and effort on reading this. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I've just added the `android` tag to your question (deduced from mentioning "Google Play Store" and from seeing you over at Android.SE ;) I have not used my Android devices for video editing yet, so I cannot give you a direct recommendation here. But while waiting for answers, be welcome to check my list of [Video Editing](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video#group_229) apps. Good luck (and, btw: well done :)

Comment: Why not run a VM with a dummy name and user account while recording the logon bit - no need to blur or pixelate then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to be a good answer for you, but you can actually just use **YouTube** again. However, you'll need to do that in the website version, since no YouTube app can do this right now. And since this involves dragging the mouse cursor, you have to do this on a computer.

(Please keep in mind that I'm new here, so I can't post more than two links, including images. I'll have to put the screenshots together into one image. Sorry about that.)

After you upload your screen capture, go to the Video Manager.
https://www.youtube.com/my_videos

There, find the video.

1. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button
2. On the new page, go to the <kbd>Enhancements</kbd> tab.
3. Switch from the <kbd>Quick fixes</kbd> tab to <kbd>Blurring effects</kbd>.
4. Click on **Custom blurring** section's <kbd>Edit</kbd> button. An overlay should appear in the middle of the screen, allowing you to customize the blur area and duration.

So, if you decide to do this on YouTube's editor, there's a great feature. When you set the red markers, it acts as a scanning area. It follows the thing around the center of the red rectangle if it moves, and blurs the selected area. It's possible to disable that with the <kbd>Lock</kbd> toggle button on the timeline.

(I think this works only if you have a decent framerate, but you will probably be fine. YouTube should do its best and use the "Motion compensation" feature of video compression. Anyways, every time I tried this with choppy screen captures, it worked fine.)

You can also see the zoom slider, making your edits a lot easier if you're working on a longer video. Dragging the red markers on the timeline item can change the blur duration.

Adding another section to be blurred is simple, you only need to go to the time where the thing you want to blur appears, and just drag your mouse on the video. Don't be confused by the height of the timeline, a vertical scrollbar will appear in case there are too many overlapping blurs.

The only downside to this I can think of is that you have to use the website and a PC browser to be able to do this. Android browsers scroll when you drag your finger across the screen, making it impossible to create a blur region. Also, a lot of browsers screw up when displaying pop-up overlays. But that's pretty much it.

Screenshot time!

[image: Four screenshots of the YouTube website.]